# SP2016 installation, password field missing in database setting

Tags: 2016, installation

I'm insttaling Sharepoint server 2016, and when i should specify database settings, it doesn't show me password field and i can get the next step, what can i do ?
[image]

Comment: Do you have display (Windows) scaling set to something greater than 100%?

Comment: yes, it is, it's work now, thx